# Python Encrypt xlsx without calling win32 COM API

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pywin32, win32com, password-encryption

Is there a feasible package that helps encrypt an xlsx/xls file without having to call win32 COM API (such as pywin32 and xlwings)?

Goal is to achieve protecting data from viewing without the password.

Reason not to use pywin32 is that it'll trigger an excel instance to manipulate excel files. For my use cases, all scripts are centrally executed on server and server has issue with excel instance or is very slow when opening an excel.

Previously stuck with reading excel with pwd, but this has been resolved by msoffcrypto-tool package which doesn't depend on win32 COM api.

Packages like openpyxl only provide workbook/worksheet protection, which doesn't really stop others from viewing the data, so unfortunately this is no go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's no effective workaroud now. Still have to use win32 API call to make it happen